# Error : MS Dynamics on-premise solution export without using "Add All Assets" in entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am having on-premise MS dynamics 2016 and we are migrating it to online 365, but we are facing some issues.

[image]

When I create a new solution using entities with selecting "Add All Assets" it works fine. (As per above image)

[image]

But when I select all assets manually (selecting all the fields, views, relationships etc, not missing even a single component in the dialog box), it's not working. Instead the wizard shows some warning of relationship, though we have selected all components displayed in the dialog box. (Also not allowing me to import in my online Dynamics 365.)

Note: I am selecting all the forms, views, charts, fields, keys, 1:N, N:1, N:N, Messages, Business Rules.

Is there anyone who is facing same problem?

Comment: Did you ever get to the cause of this? I am encountering the same issue. The primary field is not included unless I put All Assets on. i.e. Entity called "test" should have a key of "new_testid", but this is only in the solution XML if I include all-assets.

Answer (score 1):

The option to add discrete assets of entities to solutions is a feature that was introduced in Dynamics CRM 2016 (see [MSDN: Segmented solutions and patches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt628808.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I started working with them quite soon and found out that it is not bug free. The most annoying issues occur when attempting to export the solution. The export wizard often reported dependencies that obviously did not exist.

With Dynamics CRM version 8.2 a lot has been improved, but i.m.o. it's still not perfect. Especially when all assets are selected manually, dependency detection can run wild.

So, I guess you have to try another option or contact MS Support.

Comment: Thanks Henk van Boeijen for your quick and appropriate answer,Is there any link or blog in which the same problem has been described by someone else ? So I can get the reference and  we can discuss over there.If you have that link of blog or discussion forum than please share it here.